# How can I create an android application which can determine when a user has left their house?

Tags: android

I want to create an application that can determine when a user is leaving their house and remind them to take a plastic bag. I have never created an application which uses the Google Maps SDK and am stumped as to how I can make the user set their location. Are there any resources like websites or books from where I can learn the skills I need to create such an app?

I want the final application to simply send a notification when the user has left their house.

Please do suggest an alternate method if you know one. For example, I thought of using wifi to send a notification, if the user leaves their house and disconnects from the wifi they will receive a notification.

Comment: User can make its home location as favorite and app will always checks the current location through firebase. If user went few meters away from his favorite location and current location do not match with its favorite location then the app can send the notification. You can also add up wifi condition in it to make it more specific with sending notification.

Comment: This is a wrong place to ask for `any resources like websites or books from where I can learn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask for location permission in your app, users are often reluctant to give this permission, unless they have a very good reason to do so.

Checking for WiFi disconnection seems like a good idea.

You can listen for changes in network connectivity using an intent filter with `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. Register for these events in your main activity's `onResume()`:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(yourWifiBroadcastListener, filter);
```

And don't forget to unregister in `onPause()`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    this.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(yourWifiBroadcastListener);
}
```

`yourWifiBroadcastListener` is an instance of your subclass of  `android.content.BroadcastReceiver` in which you override `onReceive()` as needed:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Check wether device is connected to WiFi network 
    //and notify user on disconnection 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah that seems like a good idea to check for wifi, but keep in mind this application is not going to be released, its mostly just for myself and a school project. I want to execute the easiest way to accomplish my goal, so if it is easier to use location data, please let me know. I don't know how I can write a line of code that detecs when the wifi is connected or not? Any idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer the first few lines of code to get you started

Comment: Yup, I just made a quick test code with this code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really difficult thing to do, especially just with software.

---

GPS is maybe not the way - Consider that GPS does not work well indoors (it is 2D), and even A-GPS will have issues locating you accurately or at all in some areas, also polling GPS means you will likely get delayed updates, and it also kills battery, and added to that, no one wants you constantly tracking them so you can figure out if they need to bring a plastic bag, so perhaps you need some kind of proximity indicator instead.

Maybe listen for some kind of RF? - You could consider using BLE or UWB, and the User having a "beacon" in their home, that would be great in theory, but again no one will buy a beacon just to be reminded to bring a plastic bag.

Perhaps you could use the RSSI to their home wifi network (get them to identify it in your app), and when they are "far enough away" for a few seconds (or whatever works), send the notification - it's not perfect but if you combine it with other location solutions you could do something

You could combine approaches like these with the actual times that users typically leave their house - most people will go to work at the same time every day, maybe you could also set some kind of job to kick off at a "typical" time people leave the house, that might improve your performance a little

Comment: Thank you for responding! I never took into consideration the battery drain from GPS as well as its innacuracy, I think its best to not actively consider using GPS. I have never worked with an application that uses the RSSI of a wifi network, do you have any resources to learn this or tips I should keep in mind while I do attempt to create an application that uses RSSI data? Thanks.

Comment: You can do a quick search and read wikipedia, but I think the best thing to do is download some apps (like NRF Connect, it has a good graph) and just scan about and get an idea. Go find your home wifi (or similar) and view the RSSI graph for this over time. RSSI is just your "Received Signal Strength", based on the last received signal. I would recommend reading and experimenting a little bit more after you have got the grasp of what it is and how it sort of works